# Is there any Python Function equivalent to hsv(m) in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, colormap

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hsv.html#d123e636643
c = hsv(m) returns the colormap with m colors.
m is the Number of colors
if c=hsv(180)
the output will be

### 1.0000         0         0

```
1.0000    0.0333         0
1.0000    0.0667         0
1.0000    0.1000         0
1.0000    0.1333         0
1.0000    0.1667         0
1.0000    0.2000         0
1.0000    0.2333         0
1.0000    0.2667         0
1.0000    0.3000         0
1.0000    0.3333         0
1.0000    0.3667         0
1.0000    0.4000         0
1.0000    0.4333         0
1.0000    0.4667         0
1.0000    0.5000         0
1.0000    0.5333         0
1.0000    0.5667         0
1.0000    0.6000         0
1.0000    0.6333         0
1.0000    0.6667         0
1.0000    0.7000         0
1.0000    0.7333         0
1.0000    0.7667         0
1.0000    0.8000         0
1.0000    0.8333         0
1.0000    0.8667         0
1.0000    0.9000         0
1.0000    0.9333         0
1.0000    0.9667         0
1.0000    1.0000         0
0.9667    1.0000         0
0.9333    1.0000         0
0.9000    1.0000         0
0.8667    1.0000         0
0.8333    1.0000         0
0.8000    1.0000         0
0.7667    1.0000         0
0.7333    1.0000         0
0.7000    1.0000         0
0.6667    1.0000         0
0.6333    1.0000         0
0.6000    1.0000         0
0.5667    1.0000         0
0.5333    1.0000         0
0.5000    1.0000         0
0.4667    1.0000         0
0.4333    1.0000         0
0.4000    1.0000         0
0.3667    1.0000         0
0.3333    1.0000         0
0.3000    1.0000         0
0.2667    1.0000         0
0.2333    1.0000         0
0.2000    1.0000         0
0.1667    1.0000         0
0.1333    1.0000         0
0.1000    1.0000         0
0.0667    1.0000         0
0.0333    1.0000         0
     0    1.0000         0
     0    1.0000    0.0333
     0    1.0000    0.0667
     0    1.0000    0.1000
     0    1.0000    0.1333
     0    1.0000    0.1667
     0    1.0000    0.2000
     0    1.0000    0.2333
     0    1.0000    0.2667
     0    1.0000    0.3000
     0    1.0000    0.3333
     0    1.0000    0.3667
     0    1.0000    0.4000
     0    1.0000    0.4333
     0    1.0000    0.4667
     0    1.0000    0.5000
     0    1.0000    0.5333
     0    1.0000    0.5667
     0    1.0000    0.6000
     0    1.0000    0.6333
     0    1.0000    0.6667
     0    1.0000    0.7000
     0    1.0000    0.7333
     0    1.0000    0.7667
     0    1.0000    0.8000
     0    1.0000    0.8333
     0    1.0000    0.8667
     0    1.0000    0.9000
     0    1.0000    0.9333
     0    1.0000    0.9667
     0    1.0000    1.0000
     0    0.9667    1.0000
     0    0.9333    1.0000
     0    0.9000    1.0000
     0    0.8667    1.0000
     0    0.8333    1.0000
     0    0.8000    1.0000
     0    0.7667    1.0000
     0    0.7333    1.0000
     0    0.7000    1.0000
     0    0.6667    1.0000
     0    0.6333    1.0000
     0    0.6000    1.0000
     0    0.5667    1.0000
     0    0.5333    1.0000
     0    0.5000    1.0000
     0    0.4667    1.0000
     0    0.4333    1.0000
     0    0.4000    1.0000
     0    0.3667    1.0000
     0    0.3333    1.0000
     0    0.3000    1.0000
     0    0.2667    1.0000
     0    0.2333    1.0000
     0    0.2000    1.0000
     0    0.1667    1.0000
     0    0.1333    1.0000
     0    0.1000    1.0000
     0    0.0667    1.0000
     0    0.0333    1.0000
     0         0    1.0000
0.0333         0    1.0000
0.0667         0    1.0000
0.1000         0    1.0000
0.1333         0    1.0000
0.1667         0    1.0000
0.2000         0    1.0000
0.2333         0    1.0000
0.2667         0    1.0000
0.3000         0    1.0000
0.3333         0    1.0000
0.3667         0    1.0000
0.4000         0    1.0000
0.4333         0    1.0000
0.4667         0    1.0000
0.5000         0    1.0000
0.5333         0    1.0000
0.5667         0    1.0000
0.6000         0    1.0000
0.6333         0    1.0000
0.6667         0    1.0000
0.7000         0    1.0000
0.7333         0    1.0000
0.7667         0    1.0000
0.8000         0    1.0000
0.8333         0    1.0000
0.8667         0    1.0000
0.9000         0    1.0000
0.9333         0    1.0000
0.9667         0    1.0000
1.0000         0    1.0000
1.0000         0    0.9667
1.0000         0    0.9333
1.0000         0    0.9000
1.0000         0    0.8667
1.0000         0    0.8333
1.0000         0    0.8000
1.0000         0    0.7667
1.0000         0    0.7333
1.0000         0    0.7000
1.0000         0    0.6667
1.0000         0    0.6333
1.0000         0    0.6000
1.0000         0    0.5667
1.0000         0    0.5333
1.0000         0    0.5000
1.0000         0    0.4667
1.0000         0    0.4333
1.0000         0    0.4000
1.0000         0    0.3667
1.0000         0    0.3333
1.0000         0    0.3000
1.0000         0    0.2667
1.0000         0    0.2333
1.0000         0    0.2000
1.0000         0    0.1667
1.0000         0    0.1333
1.0000         0    0.1000
1.0000         0    0.0667
1.0000         0    0.0333
```

is there any function in python can do some thing like that
i tried to make :
color = [[x,y,z] for x in range(180) for y in  range(180) for z in range(180)]
but it didn;t do the same thing ...................................................................

Answer (score -1):

```
N = 180
HSV_tuples = [(x*1.0/N, y*1.0/N, z*1.0/N) for x, y, z in zip([1] * int(N/6) + list(range(int(N/6), 0, -1)) + [0] * int(2 * N / 6) + list(range(0, int(N/6))) + [1] * int(N/6),
                                                             list(range(0, int(N/6))) + [1]*int(2 * N / 6) + list(range(int(N/6), 0, -1))+ [0] * int(2 * N / 6),
                                                             [0] * int(2 * N / 6) + list(range(0, int(N/6))) + [1] * int(2 * N / 6)+ list(range(int(N/6), 0, -1)))]
```